# pip and Docker dependency caching

Tags: docker, pip, dockerfile, sentry

I'm trying to update the sentry logging for a Django application using Docker.

In my requirements.txt, I have only at line 213-214:

```
213: sendgrid==6.7.0
214: sentry-sdk==1.30.0
```

Note: `sendgrid==6.7.0` does not have `sentry-sdk==1.9.5` as a depdendency. I have also scanned other packages and also cannot find `sentry-sdk==1.9.5` as a dep.

When I attempt to build the application:

```
checking if image already exist remotely xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxx
⛏️ Building image. It does not exist remotely xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxx
#0 building with "engine-builder" instance using kubernetes driver
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.frontend
#1 transferring dockerfile:
#1 transferring dockerfile: 7.19kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s
#2 [internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/myuser/base-container-python-3.8-1:latest
#2 DONE 0.4s
#3 [internal] load .dockerignore
#3 transferring context: 2B done
#3 DONE 0.0s
#4 [internal] load build context
#4 DONE 0.0s
#5 [ 1/10] FROM ghcr.io/myuser/base-container-python-3.8-1:latest@sha256:xxxxxxxxxx
#5 resolve ghcr.io/myuser/base-container-python-3.8-1:latest@sha256:xxxxxxxxxx 0.0s done
#5 DONE 0.0s
#6 [auth] sharing credentials for xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
#6 DONE 0.0s
#7 importing cache manifest from xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxx:latest
#7 inferred cache manifest type: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json done
#7 DONE 0.8s
#4 [internal] load build context
#4 transferring context: 173.60MB 4.2s
#4 ...
#5 [ 1/10] FROM ghcr.io/myuser/base-container-python-3.8-1:latest@sha256:xxxxxxxxx
...
#9 [ 3/10] COPY requirements.txt ./
#9 DONE 0.0s
#10 [ 4/10] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
...
#10 21.15 Collecting sentry-sdk==1.9.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 213))
#10 21.18   Downloading sentry_sdk-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
#10 21.20      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 157.6/157.6 kB 18.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 21.20 Requirement already satisfied: sendgrid==6.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 214)) (6.7.0)
#10 21.24 ERROR: Cannot install sentry-sdk==1.30.0 and sentry-sdk==1.9.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
#10 21.24 
#10 21.24 The conflict is caused by:
#10 21.24     The user requested sentry-sdk==1.9.5
#10 21.24     The user requested sentry-sdk==1.30.0
```

This dependency conflict does not make sense - there is no `sentry-sdk==1.9.5` in requirements.txt or in the Docker image (because I built the base image and it's not there). That package might've existed in an older previous version, but if I'm running pip with the `--no-cache-dir` flag, shouldn't that purge any legacy cached version?

As a workaround I've tried `RUN pip cache purge`, as well as uninstalling sentry-sdk first, then reinstalling it from requirements.txt:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip uninstall -y sentry-sdk
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

This also does not work:

```
#10 [ 4/11] RUN pip uninstall -y sentry-sdk
#10 0.786 Found existing installation: sentry-sdk 1.30.0
#10 0.807 Uninstalling sentry-sdk-1.30.0:
#10 0.859   Successfully uninstalled sentry-sdk-1.30.0
...
Collecting sentry-sdk==1.9.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 213))
#11 20.18   Downloading sentry_sdk-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
#11 20.19      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 157.6/157.6 kB 20.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#11 20.20 Requirement already satisfied: sendgrid==6.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 214)) (6.7.0)
#11 20.23 ERROR: Cannot install sentry-sdk==1.30.0 and sentry-sdk==1.9.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
#11 20.23 
#11 20.23 The conflict is caused by:
#11 20.23     The user requested sentry-sdk==1.9.5
#11 20.23     The user requested sentry-sdk==1.30.0
```

Where could `sentry-sdk==1.9.5` be getting installed from?

Is there another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

My very hacky workaround solution to this issue was to update my Dockerfile to:

```
RUN grep -v "sentry-sdk" requirements.txt > requirements_no_sentry.txt && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements_no_sentry.txt
RUN pip uninstall -y sentry-sdk
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir sentry-sdk==1.30.0
```

essentially:

1. Don't install sentry-sdk as part of requirements.txt
2. But just in case we do install `sentry-sdk==1.9.5`, uninstall it
3. Reinstall `sentry-sdk==1.30.0`

Don't love it but it works as a temporary solution